# how to embed Canva app on our website as a iframe?

Tags: hootsuite

we are trying to integrate the Canva app on our website like Hootsuite and Publer where we can allow our customers to select the images from Canva and the same image URL will be used on our website to fulfill customer needs.

We went through the Canva developer documentation, but we couldn't understand anything over there, it would be really helpful if someone helped us to figure out the issue.